# Поддерживает ли maven зависимости модулей с двух сторон

Tags: java, maven

Поддерживает ли maven зависимости модулей с двух сторон ?

У меня есть модуль crawler-core, и crawler-module. Мне надо запускать некоторые методы crawler-module из crawler-core. А методы crawler-module также должны вызывать методы crawler-core.

И при одновременном добавлении зависимости crawler-module в crawler-core, также crawler-core в crawler-module вылетает ошибка при исполнении метода main который находится в модуле crawler-core.
Ошибка:

> Error:java: Annotation processing is not supported for module cycles. Please ensure that all modules from cycle [crawler-core,olx-module] are excluded from annotation processing

Как можно решить эту проблему ? Может это плохое проектирования проекта и надо что то делать иначе ?

Comment: *Может это плохое проектирования проекта* -- если они зависят друг от друга, возможно, они единое целое. Циклические зависимости обычно считаются признаком плохого проектирования, да.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maven не может разрешить циклические зависимости. Вам самим нужно от них избавляться. Есть несколько стратегий как это сделать: слить в один проект, или наоборот вынести общую часть в отдельный компонент, от которого будут зависеть остальные модули.